# JComponent background color using null layout?

Tags: java, swing, layout

just a short question: Is it possible to add a background color to a JComponent when it is added directly onto a JFrame using null layout? The size and position of the component are set by setBounds() and i know that the background color will not be displayed using this setup. (I know you should always use layout managers, but in this case i want to prevent this).

Comment: [Why is it frowned upon to use a null layout in SWING?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592468/why-is-it-frowned-upon-to-use-a-null-layout-in-swing)

Comment: Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). As an aside: most people around here that are worth listening to, will expect that people asking questions will fix the problem of `null` layouts (by using a layout) before seriously considering tackling other issues.

Answer (score 1):

`JComponent` is transparent by default, you'd either need to change its `opaque` state or use a `JPanel`

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                TestPane pane = new TestPane();
                pane.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 100);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setLayout(null); // This is bad, but it proofs my point
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(pane);
                frame.setSize(200, 200);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JComponent {

        public TestPane() {
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    setOpaque(!isOpaque());
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED));
        }

    }

}
```

`null` layouts are bad news, I don't condone them and you should avoid using them, the example above simply proves the point that it's the `JComponent`s `opaque` state which needs to be changed

[Why is it frowned upon to use a null layout in SWING?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592468/why-is-it-frowned-upon-to-use-a-null-layout-in-swing) is a nice read about why you should avoid using `null` layouts.

If you want more control, write your own.